# Excel Range to CSVrangeoutput - split range into groups of 41 entries

Tags: excel, vba, date-range

Im not sure exactly how to explain this in a google search so im not sure if anyone else has asked this.

I have a vba function that takes a range and turns it into a string of comma separated values.
It works like a charm.

Now i want it to only output the first 41 entries, switch down a row and output the next 41 entries in the range.

I cant quite wrap my head around it, it feels like a simple loop but i cant quite get there.

I found the csvrange macro online somewhere :)

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)    
    Dim csvRangeOutput
    Dim entry As Variant    
    For Each entry In myRange    
        If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
        End If   
    Next
    csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

Input range would look like this
[image]

Desired output would look like this, one string located in column B each group of 41 values separated on a row, offsetting 1 down each time the function hits the next nr 42.

[image]

Comment: is it something as simple as nesting another loop inside that checks a counter from the first loop against 41 and then ends and returns with a reset counter? does that even make sense

Comment: Sounds good, did you give it a try? Note that sample input data and desired output data will always help to understand what you are trying to achieve (if you include them in your question). See [mcve].

Comment: So, would you like to firstly "output the first 41 entries". In which way? Like a string of 41 entries, separated by comma, or each separated entity in a separate cell? The same for the rest of the string. And is the string less then 82 such separated elements? If not, should the operation be repeated, copying 41 entries each time?

Comment: yea one string of the 41 values, then skip one row down and a new string with the next 41 values separated by comma.

Comment: example input range would be A1:A82

Comment: expected output could be:  10356,10820,10951,10960,10972,10973,10974,10976,11015,11035,11043,11086,11115,11141,11215,11222,11323,11352,11490,11524,11604,11615,11666,11752,11770,11894,11933,12093,12153,12183,12191,12250,12346,12353,12357,12359,12389,12412,12440,12443,12451
12458,12470,12471,12482,12484,12559,12585,12709,12710,12718,12722,12723,12865,12876,12943,12978,12987,13015,13052,13065,13094,13099,13112,13119,13126,13129,13136,13145,13148,13158,13159,13229,13231,13244,13322,13369,13376,13984,14041,14043,14082

Comment: I have added some pictures, of input and output (where i manually just counted out the next 41 range)

Comment: Then, it can be solved in a much simpler way... But where to be output that string? In different columns, in a single column, or open a text document and save it as csv?

Comment: first 41 values in the activecell where you call the function, next 41 values offset row by 1, next 41 values offset row by 1 .. etc...

Comment: i have been tinkering with a do while loop but havent gotten it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Debug.Print csvRange(Selection, 41)

End Sub

Public Function csvRange(ByVal myRange As Range, ByVal Columns As Long) As String
    Dim csvRangeOutput
    Dim iCol As Long

    Dim Entry As Variant
    For Each Entry In myRange
        If Not IsEmpty(Entry.Value) Then
            iCol = iCol + 1
            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & Entry.Value
    
            If iCol = Columns Then
                csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & vbCrLf
                iCol = 0
            Else
                csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & ","
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    csvRange = Left$(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

will turn this data

[image]

into comma separated values with 41 columns

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41
42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82
83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123
124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140
```

#### Alternative

```
Public Sub Convert()
    Const ColCount As Long = 41
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To LastRow Step ColCount
        ws.Cells(iRow \ ColCount + 1, "B").Value = "'" & Join((WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A" & iRow).Resize(RowSize:=IIf(iRow + ColCount - 1 > LastRow, WorksheetFunction.Max(LastRow Mod ColCount, 2), ColCount)).Value)), ",")
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: i have all data in one column A:A and want to sort of transpose it into comma separated string of max 41 values, then skip one row down and transpose the next 41 values into one comma separated string. does that make sense?

Comment: I edited my Question with a few images of input and desired output

Comment: @MichaelChristensen where is the problem then `csvRange(Range("A1:A82"), 41)` will give you 41 values each line as output. Just adjust `A1:A82` to your range of data.

Comment: oh, the columns just confused me i think :D lemme try it out

Comment: @MichaelChristensen by columns I mean comma separated columns not Excel columns ;) sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: i cant get it to work ?  csvrange(A1:A100;41) just outputs the entire column into one string of all values, doesnt split by 41

Comment: notice the last values.. looks odd, they are not in the input data ..... 13333333 and 3333333

Comment: @MichaelChristensen check out my alternative

Comment: is the sub supposed to function?

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next code. It will do what (I understood) you need, for as many records you have in column A:A. It should be fast, using arrays and working in memory. The single iteration is for the necessary number of range slices:

```
Private Sub testStringCSVArray()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, nrSlices As Long, LastRow As Long, rngF As Range
  Dim rngStart As Range, i As Long, k As Long, h As Long, arrFin
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  LastRow = sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
  LastRow = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row of A:A
  arr = sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value             'put the range in an array

  nrSlices = UBound(arr) \ 41                    'determine the number of necessary slices
  ReDim arrFin(nrSlices + 1)
  Set rngStart = sh.Range("B" & UBound(arr) + 2) 'set the cell where the result to be returned
  For i = 1 To nrSlices + 1
      arrFin(h) = CStr(Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(arr, _
             Evaluate("row(" & k + 1 & ":" & IIf(i <= nrSlices, 41 + k, UBound(arr)) & ")"), 1)), ","))
     k = k + 41: h = h + 1
  Next i
  'Format the range where the processed data will be returned and drop the processed data array:
  With rngStart.Resize(h, 1)
      .NumberFormat = "@"
      .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrFin)
  End With
End Sub
```

In order to avoid deleting of the already processed data, in case of whishing to run the code twice or more times, the processed data will be returned in column B:B, two rows down from the last cell in column A:A. If after testing, the code proves to be reliable and no need to run it one more time, `Set rngStart = sh.Range("B" & UBound(arr) + 2)` can be modified in `Set rngStart = sh.Range("A" & UBound(arr) + 2)`.

Without preliminary formatting as text the area where the data will be dropped, Excel changes the `NumberFormat` in "scientific", when the comma delimited string contains (only) numbers of three digits each. It looks to consider the comma as a thousands separator...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223850/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-excel-range-to-csvrangeoutput-split-range-int).

Comment: @MichaelChristensen Didn't you find some time to test the code?